# How to download a file from sourceforge using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, sourceforge, invoke-webrequest

I am trying to automate updating KeePass in a few computers using powershell, so I'm interested in some sort of way to automatically download the latest release from sourceforge, however I cannot make it work. I've seen a lot of references by googling but none work for me. I'm trying this at the current time:

```
$url=https://sourceforge.net/projects/keepass/files/latest/download
#$url=https://sourceforge.net/projects/keepass/files/KeePass%202.x/2.49/KeePass-2.49-Setup.exe

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $env:USERPROFILE'\Downloads\KeePass2-Latest.exe'
```

Both of these download the web's page file, not the installer itself.

According to [this Sourceforge post](https://sourceforge.net/p/forge/site-support/5109/) "*The regular download link will work, as long as the download function is able to follow redirects, and does not appear to be a browser source (eg., doesn't have a browser-like User-Agent String), it will simply redirect to the file itself.*"

However it's not working for me, I'm not specifying any UserAgent, and I've even tried to use `-UserAgent $null` as a parameter, but no luck.

Is there a way to programatically download from sourceforge using command-line/Powershell?

Comment: Consider a tool like chocolatey to update tools aka a package manager for software?

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts although I can consider it, I like things to be as much "DIY" as possible so I don't have to rely on hundreds of external dependencies on my work pipeline. It's a good suggestion but not an answer to what I asked. Thank you anyways!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the documentation, the default user agent of [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest) is similar to:

> `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Microsoft Windows 10.0.15063; en-US) PowerShell/6.0.0`

This might be interpreted as a browser user agent by [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/) and therefore might not be a good candidate to be redirected immediately.

The [documentation](https://sourceforge.net/p/forge/documentation/Downloading%20files%20via%20the%20command%20line/#bonus-round) of SourceForge states, that they offer a direct download, when using `wget` for example:

> We also have a special "latest/download" URL that's a bit like Google's "I'm Feeling Lucky" button for downloads:
>
> ```
> $ wget https://sourceforge.net/projects/phppgadmin/files/latest/download
> ```
>
> If you use it we’ll try to send you the latest download. Wget (and similar tools) makes it a little tricky to figure out if you’re on Windows, a Mac, Linux, etc. If you’re downloading something that’s OS-specific you’re better off using the full URL.

The default user agent of `wget` looks like the following, where the number represents the current version of `wget`:

| OS | User agent |
| --- | --- |
| Windows | `Wget/1.21.1` |
| Linux | `Wget/1.21.1 (linux-gnu)` |

Using just `Wget` as the user agent will already be enough to donwload the executable directly:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -UserAgent "Wget" -Uri https://sourceforge.net/projects/keepass/files/latest/download -OutFile $env:USERPROFILE'\Downloads\KeePass2-Latest.exe'
```

As KeePass only offers a Windows executable anyway, you don't have to worry about Linux or macOS binaries/packages.

Comment: This feels more like a workaround, but it works so I will not complain! Thank you a lot!

Comment: @rovda You can ask https://sourceforge.net/ on which strings they guarantee to redirect immediately to the desired file, to make it feel less like a workaround.